# Show that $m(\{ x : f^*(x) > \alpha\}) \ge c'/\alpha$, where $f^*$ is a maximal function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm struggling to solve an exercise 4 of chapter 3 in Stein's Real Analysis.

[image]

I've dealt with the former ones ($f^*$ is lower bounded), but I'm not sure how to handle the red lines above.

To start with, I can't fully understand the meaning of the previous sentence; show that the weak type estimate for all $\alpha > 0$ whenever $\int |f| = 1$ is best possible in the following sense.

Also, the Chebyshev inequality leads to the opposite inequality, so it isn't useful for the problem.

Then, I've used the definition of maximal function as follows:

$f^*(x) = 1/m(B) > \alpha$, ($B$ contains unit ball) -> $m(B) < 1/\alpha$

but this doesn't help prove the problem.

So, I'm stuck on here,,

Any comments about this problem would be grateful. Thanks.

cf)

if $f$ is integrable on $\Bbb R^d$, we define its **maximal function** $f^*$ as follows;

$$
f^*(x) = sup_{x \in B} \frac{1}{m(B)} \int_B |f(y)|dy, ~~x \in \Bbb R^d
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$\int_{B_1} |f(y)|\, dy >0$$ where $B_1$ is a fixed ball centered in $x_0$ with a diamether $1.$

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $||x-x_0|| \geq 1$ we, then, have
$$ f^*(x) = \sup \frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B |f(y)| \, dy \geq \frac{1}{m(B')} \int_{B'} |f(y)| \, dy,$$
where $B'$ is the smallest ball centered at $y$ which contains ball $B_1.$
Notice that $m(B')=(||x-x_0||+1)^d m(B_1),$ and use that in previous inequation.

Edit:

For the red part of exercise use function $f=\frac{1}{v_d}\chi_{B_1}$ where $v_d$ is the volume of unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d.$
Notice that for $x \in \overline B_1$ $$f^*(x)=\frac{1}{v_d}.$$ If $||x||> 1$ then if $B$ doesn't intersect the ball $B_1$ we have that $$\int_B |f(y)| \, dy = 0.$$ Let $B$ be the smallest ball such that $x \in \overline{B}$ and $B_1 \subset B.$ The radius of such ball is $\frac{||x||+1}{2}.$ For a such ball we have
$$f^*(x) \geq \frac{1}{m(B)} \int_B |f(y)|\, dy \geq \frac{1}{\left(\frac{||x||+1}{2}\right)^d v_d} \int_{B_1} |f(y)|\, dy \geq \frac{2^d}{(||x||+1)^dv_d}.$$
For every $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{v_d}$ we have that
$$ \{ x : f^*(x) > \alpha \} \supseteq \{x : \frac{2^d}{(||x||+1)^dv_d} > \alpha \} = \{x : ||x|| < \frac{2}{\sqrt[d]{v_d \alpha}}-1\}$$

So we have
$$m(\{x : f^*(x)> \alpha\}) \geq \left(\frac{2}{(v_d\alpha)^\frac{1}{d}} -1 \right)^d v_d.$$

Now we use basics to prove
$$\left(\frac{2}{(v_d\alpha)^\frac{1}{d}} - 1\right)^d v_d \geq \frac{c'}{\alpha},$$ for some small $\alpha.$

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have a question about your answer. After the line $0 < \alpha < 1/v_d$, the set relationship isn' t clear for me. Since $f^*(x) \le (2/(|x|-1))^d*v_d^{-1}$, I guess the direction of the inequality should be opposite; $\{x : f^*(x) > \alpha \} \subset \{x : (2/(|x|-1))^d*v_d^(-1) > \alpha \}$. Could you explain more in detail about this point?; whether there was a typo, or what I'm missing etc.

Comment: There was the mistake in that line. I have edited the solution, and i think it is ok now. Please, check. Now there are some parts of solutions that is unnecessary

Comment: Ok, now I see. BTW, the small $\alpha$ in the final line seems to be $0 < \alpha < 1/v_d$, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right...

Comment: @V.J. Hi, just stumbled across this problem now. What allows you to "choose" $f= \frac{1}{v_d} \chi_{B_1}$ for the red part of the exercise? The way I read the problem, we are to show the conclusion (in red) holds for all integrable $f$ with $f$ not identically zero and $\int |f| = 1$. Am I misunderstanding the problem? Is it because $f$ is supported on the unit ball?

Comment: Maybe I understand it incorrectly. I found a function which shows that given estimate is best posible. But proof will work for all function with $\int |f| =1$ which is supported in a unit ball. Only difference will be that $f^*$ don't need to be equal $1/v_d$ on the ball $B_1.$ That does not change rest of the proof.